# How to make a Feature Receiver in sp 2010

Tags: 2010

I am following this tutorial but for 2010
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc406686%28office.12%29.aspx

I am in this part

How can I make a feature receiver in sp 2010?

Feature Receiver

Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 added the Feature framework, which provides SharePoint site developers and owners a way to inject functionality into existing sites and deploy custom solutions, such as workflow templates that are developed in Microsoft Visual Studio. Features can also be used for timer job deployment. Although the Feature schema does not provide a way to do this, the Feature **Activated** and **Deactivating** events can be caught with custom code to handle the installation and uninstallation of a timer job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Visual Studio 2010 solution, select the feature you want to have a receiver. Then right click the same and from the context menu, select event receivers. This will add another cs file in the feature structure/folder. This file has all the necessary events like FeatureActivated FeatureInstalled etc.. commented out initially. 
From there you can uncomment the desired event say FeatureActivated and write the code in there.

Comment: Thank you but I am a little confused.
1st. The timer job is a class library not a sharepoint project.

so , Should I create a new vs 2010 solution with an empty sharepoint 2010 project, and then what?

Comment: 1. Yes create an empty SharePoint project.
2. Add all the classes to the solution except the one mentioned under Deploying Custom Timer Jobs->Feature Receiver
you may need to update the namespace referred those classes.
3. Add a new feature to your Solution.
4. Follow the above steps to generate a feature receiver.
5. Copy the code from Custom Timer Jobs->Feature Receiver on MSDN to your feature receiver class.

Comment: It compiled, but when I press F5 to deploy I got this error.

Error 1 Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  0 0 TimerSitoJob